# Gatsby Images in different folder to markdown

Tags: image, markdown, relative-path, gatsby

I've got an issue trying to reference images that are not in my md folder with AllMarkdownRemark. I've tried and failed to find solutions, including:

1. Using relative paths
2. Using string syntax
3. Trying to create an alternative source with the file-system plugin

In my src folder I have a md folder containing markdown files, and an images folder containing the images. The head of an md file looks like this:

```
---
path: "/blog/2018"
date: "2018-11-07"
title: "My first blog post - THIS IS A TEST!"
image: "../images/space2.jpg"
--
```

My graphql query on the blog page looks like this:

```
query {
  allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC}) {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        id
        html
        frontmatter {
          title
          path
          date(formatString: "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")
          image {
                childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 1440) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
          }

       }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is returning a string because the images folder can't be found by allmarkdownremark. But I have this in my gatsby-config, meaning it should work:

```
{
        resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
        options: {
            path: `${__dirname}/src/md/`,
            name: "markdown-pages"
        },
    },
    {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
        options: {
            path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
            name: "images"
        },
    },
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-images/

Comment: what is exactly the error message? Could it be that you have an empty string for `image` field in one of your markdown files?

Comment: Hi Derek, I actually managed to get this sorted. The issue was using the Gatsby background-image plugin, it's clearly not been updated and so was creating issues. Thanks for helping out!